# On GitHub "Network" page, how to center on last commit (not just last commit to master)?

Tags: github

I use GitHub's "Network" page a lot: https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Anki-Android/network

Unfortunately it centers on the latest commit to master, and we do most of the work in branches, so the latest commits are usually pages away, and I have to scroll a lot to the right.

Is there any trick to center on the latest commit instead?

(last commit in any branch, not just last commit in master)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an option on the Network graph. Or at least not currently.

The Network graph also opens up centred with the branch that has been set as default by the repo/fork owner(s), not necessarily the "master" branch. (Don't change your default branches after viewing the graph because the cache will still open up on the last set default branch.)

Unfortunately it would not be a way to show up the last commit dot on the graph (if you made the branch containing the newest commits as default) either.

This is because it is based on the fork/source currently viewed and not last commit across all forks of the original.